# Is it possible to start building a credit history in the US as a tourist on a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: usa, credit-history

There's a good chance that early spring next year I'll be relocating to the US. From what others told me, it can be a pain to start out in the States with no credit history as everything relies on you having a credit score. Given that I frequently travel to the US, I was thinking I could circumvent the usual difficulties by building up my credit history far in advance.

My plan is:

1. Open up a bank account in the US (I know this is possible with Wells Fargo)
2. Get a secured credit card
3. Spend as much as possible on said credit card every month
4. Slowly increase my credit rating to the point where it's reasonable in 9 months when I make the move

Is my plan feasible or is there a "catch" I'm missing?

Comment: The US credit rating bureaus index by an individual's name, date of birth, physical address, and Social Security Number. I imagine that the fewer of those items you present, the less likely it is that your data will be computed and made available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could theoretically work but I believe you'll need a social security number to build a credit history (the social security number is the key by which the credit history is looked up) and you can't get a social security number just with a B1/B2 — you need a visa that provides work authorization. If you don't have a social security number already, it's going to be tough.